# nsis language selection items and special characters

Tags: localization, special-characters, nsis

I am using nsis - MUI to create installer. I am facing a problem that when I do something like this:

```
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Czech"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Slovak"
```

... in selection of language during the instalation I am getting names of languages withou special character.

So for Czech language I am getting "Cesky" instead of "Česky". Is there any possibility how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language name displayed by MUI/LangDLL depends on the NSIS version:

For the official NSIS 2.46 you can probably edit Czech.nsh (This should work correctly as long as you don't define MUI_LANGDLL_ALLLANGUAGES, if you do then "Č" might be displayed as something else.)

For the Unicode fork, compiling as Unicode should have no problems.

For NSIS 3 (if you compiled from SVN yourself), Unicode should have no problems and ANSI is currently restricted to ASCII only for the language name.